# Angular.js callback from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular project I'm using [Angular.js material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/). And I want to show `$mdialog` with custom controller, where user changes some data and this data should be applied to my `$scope` variable. Example what I do now:

```
function myControllerFn($scope, MyService){
   // I do copy of my service variable because I don't want to change it until user will click save button
   $scope.name = angular.copy(MyService.name); 

   $scope.editCurrentProfile = function() {
       $scope.showEditProfileDialog($scope.name).then(function(name){
                    $scope.name = name;
       }
   }

   $scope.showEditProfileDialog = function(name) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $mdDialog.show({
         controller: 'editProfileViewCtrl',
         templateUrl: 'controllers/editProfileDialog.tmpl.html',
         locals: {
             name: name,
             deferred: deferred
         }
      });
         return deferred.promise;
     };
}
```

Then in dialog controller I do:

```
function editProfileViewCtrl($scope, name, deffered) {
    deferred.resolve('newName');
}
```

But I think it is the wrong way. So what is the best way to communicate between two view controllers in angular without new service ? Or better create another service like: `EditDialogService`, where I will save results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a modal, the `show()` function returns a promise.

```
$scope.showEditProfileDialog = function(name) {
  var modalInstance = $mdDialog.show({
     controller: 'editProfileViewCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'controllers/editProfileDialog.tmpl.html',
     locals: {
         name: name
     }
  });

   modalInstance.then(function(result){
      // acces what is returned
      // In your case, you would do
      $scope.name = result;
   }, function(error){
      // Usually when you cancel your modal
   });
 }
```

Your modal controller can be injected with `$mdDialog`.

```
function editProfileViewCtrl($scope, name, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.close = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide('newName');
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, sorry. Found it ! A promise that can be resolved with $mdDialog.hide() or rejected with $mdDialog.cancel(). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should create a directive with your user as scope variable. Angular in itself is handling the data binding.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to create a minimal controller function that has access to $scope.

```
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: function () { this.parent = $scope; },
  templateUrl: 'controllers/editProfileDialog.tmpl.html',
  locals: {
     name: name,
     deferred: deferred
  }
});
```